# logical statement with complex syntax

Tags: regex, logical-operators

I found a shirt with some regex on it that is supposed to be a shake spear quote. Can someone explain how it can be translated to "2b or not 2b"?

```
/((bb)|(b|b[^b]|[^b])*b?)/
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a *logical* statement? Looks like a regular expression.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular expression (regex).

In Perl regular expressions, `/` denotes the beginning or end of the regex. `|` means "or" and `^` means "not". Parentheses denote group in which the order of the contents matters and square brackets denote a group where the order of the contents does not matter. `?` means match the preceding pattern either once or not at all.

Given a string,

```
(bb)
```

matches the exact string `bb`. This is the part that denotes "to be."

```
(b|b[^b]|[^b])*b?
```

Within the group, it matches `b`, or `b` followed by any character other than `b`, or just any character other than `b`. Adding `*` to the end of this group matches it 0 or more times. `b?` on the end means you have a trailing `b` or you don't. This is supposed to denote "not to be," though it is possible to match `bb` with this portion as well.

You have an extraneous close paren `)` after `?`.

The Shakespeare quote is "to be or not to be," stylized as "2b or not 2b."